# Computer Graphics: Strategy for inheriting rotations in an animation tree

Tags: opengl, graphics

When animations are organized as a tree, such that child shapes inherit rotations and translations from parent shapes, is there a common strategy for inheriting rotations?

Consider an arm that can rotate about the shoulder, elbow, and wrist. Each segment of the arm inherits some rotation from the segment above it and each segment might also have some independent rotation. It seems that the order of steps to determine the position of the hand is this:

1) Position the hand as though the wrist is at the origin and perform any rotation about the wrist that applies only to the hand.

2) Position the resulting hand as though the wrist is attached to the forearm, position the elbow at the origin, and perform any rotation about the elbow that applies only to the forearm.

3) Position the resulting hand as though the elbow is attached to the upper arm, position the shoulder at the origin, and perform any rotation about the shoulder that applies only to the upper arm.

4) Translate the resulting hand relative to the actual position of the shoulder.

Is there a more efficient strategy? If not, what is the best way to implement this in a tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what the classic OpenGL fixed pipeline matrix stack would achieve. Rendering would proceed as:

- push matrix for shoulder;
- draw shoulder;
- call to draw elbow;
- pop matrix for shoulder.

The elbow would push its matrix, draw, call to draw its children, pop its matrix and return. And so on, down your tree of local spaces.

That effectively reproduces your tree on the call stack. So if you prefer you can do the same thing by pushing an identity transformation from the root and having each node draw according to the transformation it receives, adding its transform and passing on to the children.

So the answer is, in short: no, there's no more efficient way to compose the transformations than walking around the tree composing the transformations.

Comment: Thanks. On the face of it, your stack seems more efficient than my understanding of the situation. For instance, to draw the forearm, it is necessary to compute the position of the upper arm. But then, to draw the hand, it seems it is still necessary to go through the steps in the OP even though some of this seems like a re-computation. Do I misunderstand?

Comment: There's no recomputation. If you have the individual transforms `A`, `B`, `C` & `D`, with objects `O1` which is drawn with transform `A`, `O2`, which is drawn with the composition `AB`, `O3` which is drawn with `ABC` and `O4` which is drawn with `ABCD` then you do a total of three transformation compositions to draw the entire model. You work out `AB` once, then use that to get `ABC`, and that to get `ABCD`. Every calculation occurs exactly once.

Answer (score 2):

This is also known as a scene graph, there are many API's with simply implement this paradigm.

Typically you can insert a mesh (and even have it animated) at a transformation node in said graph.

When designing one you do not have to go to that level of complexity (for example you may decide that there is no reason to move the wrist, hand or fingers programatically therefore you can simply attach them to the forearm group (or alternatively use a animated mesh and have a separate animation for fingers and hand moving which can be triggered based on some form of event.

This strategy is actually extremely efficient because it allows you to perform extremely complex operations on a large variety of shapes in a uniform and grouped manner.

When putting together a game typically one would create a mesh of characters and include all of the relevant animations for it, which in turn could be treated as a single object within a scene graph (with no smaller objects inside).